# Проблема с кодировкой vkontakte-api

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, url

Пытаюсь отправить сообщение через vkapi messages.send.

```
try {
    String message =("Привет (  ) Hello");
    String userid=("2453647");
    String token=("а7563894389573y87g4fuyi89w");//Просто набор символов
    String ramdomid=("3249324835");
    URL outurl = new URL("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?random_id="+ramdomid+"&peer_id="+userid+"&message="+message+"&v=5.67&access_token="+token);
    LineNumberReader outreader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(outurl.openStream(),"UTF-8"));
    System.out.println(outreader.readLine());
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Получаю (java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:)
Перебирал кодировки в одной нет русских букв в другой пробела нет)
Прошу помощи.

Comment: как вы выполняет этот запрос? добавьте код. и почему не используете java api?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman Спасибо, поправил. Про java api не стал заморачиваться приложение просто должно отправить сообщение.

Comment: вам же все равно надо аутентифицироваться и послать сообщение, а api позволяет это сделать проще, чем писать самому. если я правильно помню, то надо использовать POST, а не GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    String message =("Привет (  ) Hello");
    message = URLEncoder.encode(message,"UTF-8");//перекодировать в UTF-8
    String userid=("2453647");
    String token=("а7563894389573y87g4fuyi89w");//Просто набор символов
    String ramdomid=("3249324835");
    URL outurl = new URL("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?random_id="+ramdomid+"&peer_id="+userid+"&message="+message+"&v=5.67&access_token="+token);
    LineNumberReader outreader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(outurl.openStream(),"UTF-8"));
    System.out.println(outreader.readLine());
} catch (IOException|UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Если использовать POST, то ненужно будет перекодировать

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Спасибо ,буду знать.